# iconv cannot convert given characters

Tags: character-encoding

I just wanted to convert a txt file to UTF-8, since cat displays it correctly, but vi or gedit doesn't:

```
$ cat test.txt 
>#
>‹
|
||
°
├──
└──
_
__
$ iconv -f WINDOWS-1253 -t UTF-8 test.txt 
>#
>β€Ή
|
||
Β°
β”iconv: illegal input sequence at position 18
$
```

**Q**: how can I convert my txt to UTF-8? iconv doesn't works.

Comment: Could you show us the output of `file test.txt`? Are you _sure_ it's not already utf8?

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains characters such as `├` and `└` which are not in [Windows-1253](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1253), so whether the `iconv` fails or not, you did not specify the correct input encoding and therefore the output is wrong.

If `cat` displays the file correctly, then the file's encoding is the same as your terminal's. Run the command `locale` and look at the `LC_CTYPE` line to see what encoding your terminal is using. It's likely that the file is, in fact, already encoded in UTF-8.

It seems that Vi and Gedit are failing to detect the encoding of the file automatically. Have you configured them to assume a particular encoding? If so, don't do that. If not, in Gedit, select “UTF-8” instead of “automatically detected” when opening the file. In Vim, use `:set encoding=utf-8`.

Answer (score 1):

The source characters look like it may be ATARI. Try -f ATARI or -f ATARIST